# Alexa Drop In on AmazonTap

Tags: alexa

Is Drop In on the Alexa App not available on the Amazon Tap?  I can't seem to enable it.  There's no option for Drop In at all on my Tap.

Answer (score 5):

As of now it's not supported.

> ### Compatible Devices
>
> Echo
>
> Echo Dot (1st Generation)
>
> Echo Dot (2nd Generation)
>
> Echo Show
>
> Alexa app (only for starting Drop In)

([Amazon help](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=help_search_1-2?ie=UTF8&nodeId=202153130&qid=1506003351&sr=1-2))